# ffmpeg halt when I turn video into image

Tags: ffmpeg

My command is:
`ffmpeg -threads 1 -i http://illegal-video.nos.netease.com/hDHnMXpHywUcs2q7.mp4 -vf fps=1/5.0 C:\Users\Roomy\Desktop\test\image%d.jpg`

but I got 
[image]

And ffmpeg is halt when the error occurs.

Is that a bug?

Comment: Download the video and try.

Comment: @Gyan I download the video and try again,It works,but is there a way that I can detect the video without download?